# Mixin overshadowing

Tags: dart

Let's say i have code like this :

```dart
class A{ foo() => "A";}
class B{ foo() => "B";}
class C{ foo() => "C";}

class Mix extends A with B,C {
  foo() => "MIX";
  bar() => super.foo();
}

class MessABC = Object with A,B,C;
class MessBCA = Object with B,C,A;
class MessCAB = Object with C,A,B;

void main() {
  Mix mix = new Mix();
  MessABC mABC = new MessABC();
  MessBCA mBCA = new MessBCA();
  MessCAB mCAB = new MessCAB();

  print("Mix.foo = ${mix.foo()} Mix.bar = ${mix.bar()} \n"
        "mABC.foo = ${mABC.foo()} \n"
        "mBCA.foo = ${mBCA.foo()} \n"
        "mCAB.foo = ${mCAB.foo()} \n");

}
```

The output

> Mix.foo = MIX Mix.bar = C
>   mABC.foo = C
>   mBCA.foo = A
>   mCAB.foo = B

On the `mix` object I can call both `Mix.foo` and `C.foo` with the **super** *(actually i expected `A.foo`)* 
But can i somehow call  `A.foo` and `B.foo` ?

Also i am a bit confused by the **with** semantics. `A,B,C` Looks like "one rank enumeration" but the order is important. And "Dart Editor" doesn't warn me about the name collision. Perhaps i can enable this warning?

*To me it feels like something that makes you confused and error-prone.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Mixin application is processed from left to right.

The superclass of `Object with A,B,C` is `Object with A,B`, which again has the superclasses `Object with A` and then `Object`.

The overriding rules for mixins are the same as for non-mixin superclasses. Your `C.foo` in `Mix` overrides the ones inherited from `A` and `B`, so `Mix.bar`'s `super.foo()` only reaches the `C.foo`, and there is no way to access `A.foo` or `B.foo`.

Overriding is perfectly ok, and doesn't cause any warnings, as long as the methods have compatible signatures.

The most thorough description of mixins is still https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/

Comment: It's unfortunate that `(mBCA as B).foo()`does not take `foo()` from B and print B then. It would be so great to take those certain overrides in the mixin structure and enable interlinking mixins, that can access sub- or parent mixens and their values