# How do I use Mixins without inheritance?

Tags: dart, mixins

Is it possible to apply a mixin to a class without the target class inheriting from any other class? For example, can I implement the following:

```
class User with Persistence {
  // implementation
}
```

Most of your examples of Mixins in dart seem to be coupled with inheritance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to inherit from another class if you want to use a mixin. However, you can simply inherit from Object:

```dart
class User extends Object with Persistence {
  // implementation
}
```

But really, you can just inherit from Persistence as well which will have the same effect:

```dart
class User extends Persistance {
  // implementation
}
```

Gilad Bracha [explains](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=17164) that the syntax is specifically designed this way:

> I think it is important to understand the semantic model here. "with"
>   is the mixin application operator, and it takes two parameters: a
>   superclass and a mixin, and yields a class. Saying "with Foo" in
>   isolation makes as much sense as saying >> 2 (you could interpret both
>   as curried functions, but that is very far from Dart). When you write
>   "C extends S with M", you are specifying a superclass following the
>   extends keyword, just as you do when you write "C extends K" except
>   that the superclass is not specified via an identifier but via a mixin
>   application. So the superclass would be "S with M".
>
> As Lasse points out, as practical matter it doesn't restrict you, but
>   having the syntax reflect the underlying structure is important.

Comment: So going by Gilad's explanation, if the `with` is an operator then the that takes the superclass and a mixin as operands and returns a new class, then the code `class C extends S with M` would be equivalent to `class C extends (S with M)` as if to say `C` extends a class which is the result of `M` mixed-in with `S`.

Comment: I was confused by mixins and @lrn gave me this explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465187/mixin-overshadowing/23465587#23465587

Comment: That also is a useful point. However, my question was about the fact that I cannot mix-in classes without considering the target class to extend from a super-class. @Pixel Elephant's suggestion to extend `Object` when required can help me do that.

Comment: Exactly correct interpretation of Gilad's explanation. You can think of Dart having only one mixin operation, `class X = Y with Z;`, and everything else can be reduced to that. When you have `class C extends D with E ... ` it's really `class DwithE = D with E; class C extends DwithE ...`. When you have `... D with E, F ...`, it's really `class DwithE = D with E; class DwithEF = DwithE with F; ... DwithEF ...`. You are allowed to write "class C extends D with E, F {" inline, but it really does introduce two extra anonymous classes, and the superclass chain is `DwithEF`, `DWithE`, `D`, `Object`.